# Blackberry ssl with smtp

Tags: blackberry, java-me, smtp

Hy,
I try to send mail throught an smtp server.
It works fine with normal connection but when i try to use ssl with gmail. It makes a strange problem.

> 1. [180.882] [RECV] 220 smtp.inmail24.com ESMTP **extMailer** (smtp)
> 2. [180.882] [SEND] EHLO localhost
> 3. [181.156] [RECV] 250-smtp.inmail24.com
> 4. [181.156] [RECV] 250-PIPELINING
> 5. [181.156] [RECV] 250-SIZE 13631488
> 6. [181.156] [RECV] 250-ETRN
> 7. [181.156] [RECV] 250-STARTTLS
> 8. [181.156] [RECV] 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
> 9. [181.156] [RECV] 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
> 10. [181.156] [RECV] 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> 11. [181.156] [RECV] 250-8BITMIME
> 12. [181.156] [RECV] 250 DSN
> 13. [181.164] [SEND] AUTH PLAIN "The auth plain"
> 14. [181.742] [RECV] 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
> 15. [181.75] [SEND] MAIL FROM:
> 16. [182.023] [RECV] 250 2.1.0 Ok
> 17. [182.031] [SEND] RCPT TO:
> 18. [182.195] [RECV] 250 2.1.5 Ok
> 19. [182.195] [SEND] DATA
> 20. [182.304] [RECV] 354 End data with .
> 21. [182.304] [SEND] From: asdasd@inmail24.com
> 22. [182.304] [SEND] Message-ID:
> 23. [182.312] [SEND] To: mailto@gmail.com
> 24. [182.312] [SEND] Subject: Test mail without SSL - 2011-11-09 07:31:34
> 25. [182.312] [SEND] Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2011 07:31:56 GMT-0400
> 26. [182.312] [SEND]
> 27. [182.312] [SEND] TestMessage
> 28. [182.32] [SEND] .
> 29. [182.453] [RECV] 250 2.0.0 Ok, id=28522-10, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10027): 250 2.0.0 Ok:  queued as 2537340E254E
> 30. [182.453] [SEND] QUIT
> 31. [182.515] [RECV] 221 2.0.0 Bye

But when i trying to use smtp with gmail and ssl

> 1. SSL:->CH
> 2. SSL:<-SH
> 3. SSL:<-SC
> 4. SSL:<-SHD
> 5. SSL:->CKE
> 6. SSL:->CCS
> 7. SSL:->F
> 8. SSL:<-F
> 9. [RECV] 220 mx.google.com ESMTP jb5sm6904507lab.15
> 10. [SEND] EHLO localhost:465

and no recv message :(
Just a timeout after a few second

I use j2me because i make this app for blackberry
Thanks for replys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to include a port number after the hostname in your `EHLO` command.  Once you have established a connection and received the `220` greeting successfully, you do not have to do anything different in your commands then you were previously doing.

With that said, you might consider using port 587 with the `STARTTLS` command instead.  TLS is more secure than SSL, and `STARTTLS` allows you to query the server to make sure it supports SSL/TLS before you activate it.

Comment: How to send the STARTTLS?
Cause now:
make connection 
 1. recieve (i recieve 220 mx.google.com ESMTP jb5sm6904507lab.15)
 2. i send "EHLO localhost"
 3. recieve but nothing arrive here :(

Comment: Do everything you were previously doing on port 25, just on port 587 instead.  Leave SSL/TLS initially deactivated. After receiving the first `EHLO` reply, before sending `AUTH`, send `STARTTLS`.  If a success reply is received, activate SSL/TLS and send a new `EHLO`, then continue on normally.